# Django contrib.auth without permissions

Tags: python, django, authentication

Is it possible to use the built-in django.contrib.auth mechanism without enabling permissions at all?
I just need a simple registration and login system.

Thanks.

Comment: No, unfortunately, the permissions are bundled and quite tightly coupled with the permissions. Is there a reason why you want this?

Comment: just keeping things simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you mean, really. Although the permissions are part of the auth app, there's no requirement to actually assign any, or check them at any point: that's entirely up to you. Most of the projects I have done use auth in exactly this way, to check logins and nothing else.